# How to reinstall a package

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I am getting this while installing libebml3:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
libebml3:i386
Error in function: 
dpkg: error processing libebml3:i386 (--configure):
Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
reinstall it before attempting configuration.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 29):

Since I happened to have the same problem with another package, wanting a reinstall, and all the methods in the answers *either did nothing* or first *uninstall the whole system* before reinstalling, I ended up with a solution.

```
sudo aptitude reinstall libebml3:i386
```

Of course, there must be another solution to force a package to reinstall using apt-get instead of aptitude.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libebml3:i386
```

Comment: Good, unless you need to reinstall a package that aptitude depends on (like libboost_iostreams).

Comment: Using `man apt-get` the solution appears : `--reinstall    Re-Install packages that are already installed and at the newest version.`

Answer (score 11):

```
dpkg -r libebml3:i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

do those steps in terminal .

Answer (score 4):

You could remove the program by entering the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libebml3
sudo apt-get install libebm13
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 3):

Type following commands in a terminal (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
sudo dpkg -p libebml3:i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
```