# Broken package ubuntuone-control-panel-qt

Tags: python, power-management, dpkg

An interrupted installation of updates resulted in ubuntuone-control-panel-qt breaking and now I cannot install or update anything. There seems to be an error in python2.7 -

```
ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata_nd
dpkg: error processing archive ubuntuone-control-panel-qt_13.09-0ubuntu1_all.deb (--install):
```

When I try to reinstall the package via .deb

`a dpkg --audit` yields:

> The following packages are in a mess due to serious problems during
>   installation.  They must be reinstalled for them (and any packages
>   that depend on them) to function properly:
>   ⠀python-pexpect       Python module for automating interactive applications
>   ⠀ubuntuone-control-panel-qt Ubuntu One Control Panel - Qt frontend
>   ⠀hplip-data           HP Linux Printing and Imaging - data files
>   ⠀python-libxml2       Python bindings for the GNOME XML library
>   ⠀apport               automatically generate crash reports for debugging
>
> The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
>   configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried using
>   dpkg --configure  or the configure menu option in dselect:
>   ⠀python-ubuntuone-client Ubuntu One client Python libraries
>   ⠀python-ubuntuone-control-panel Ubuntu One Control Panel - Python Libraries

--configure  or --configure -a doesn't work

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1433

If you have "Synaptic" package manager installed, launch that program and on the left panel is a choice for "Broken" packages. Use Synaptic to try to fix them or remove them.

Lastly, you can try to reinstall and "force" the package to be installed: [How to reinstall a package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207475/how-to-reinstall-a-package)

Comment: Cant seem to run Synaptic - E: The package ubuntuone-control-panel-qt needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
E: Internal error opening cache (1). Please report.

Comment: Also cannot reinstall it, keep getting the same error - E: The package ubuntuone-control-panel-qt needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/all/ubuntuone-control-panel-qt/download 
Download the .deb file, click it and see if this installs. The one thing I don't like about Ubuntu is that if 1 package is broken, it holds up others from installing